# Custom objective function in xgboost for Regression

Tags: regression, python, loss-functions, boosting

I am working on a regression problem, where I want to modify the loss function in xgboost library such that my predictions should never be less than the actual value. I have written this code:

```
def custom_loss(preds, dtrain):
   labels = dtrain.get_label()
   df = preds - labels
   df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['val'])
   df['valg'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: 10*abs(x) if x<0 else x)
   grad = df['valg'].as_matrix()
   return preds-labels, grad
```

This essentially means that I want to penalize those predictions which are less than my actual value more. However, this isn't working and there is no improvement in my predictions. Can anyone help me figure out where I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Python Script:

```
params = {"booster" : "gbtree",
  "eta": 0.20,
  "max_depth": 4,
  "subsample": 0.75,
  "colsample_bytree": 0.65,
  "silent": 1,
  "eval_metric": "rmse",
  }

num_round = 400

def custom_loss(preds, dtrain):
    labels = dtrain.get_label()
    df = preds - labels
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['val'])
    df['valg'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: 5*abs(x) if x<0 else x)
    grad = df['valg'].as_matrix()
    return preds-labels, grad


dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train.drop('price_act', axis=1), 
label=X_train['price_act'])
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test.drop('price_act',axis=1), 
label=X_test['price_act'])

watchlist = [(dtrain,'train'), (dtest,'eval')]

bst = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_round, watchlist, custom_loss)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard. How to have the code formatted/highlighted as you did though?

Comment: I only corrected minuscule typos, as you can see, when you click on "edited ... hours ago". Code formatting apparently happend all by itself.

Comment: I am a beginner in data science myself so not very sure of this but I think you need to give the hessian(derivative of the gradient) as well for xgboost.